# FileSystemWatcher stop working suddenly if trying to Copy-Item

Tags: powershell, events, scripting, filesystemwatcher

I have at work some little issue that I want to solve using a script.

**Background**

- We access the network from another company (a bigger one) by using a virtual machine (**VM**).
- Sometimes new files are added in the virtual machine and we have to download it. The problem is, that we do not know when they are going to upload something, or what.
- I want to run a script that

  - detects new files created
  - copy them using a temporary server
  - the temporary server is between the VM and our local computer

**Some more information**

- I am pretty new in Powershell. I understand some of the code below (copy, move, create directory, etc) but some other parts are copy paste from internet and I do not understand how they work(FileSystemWatcher and Subscription of events).
- For me it is enough for now if it works (I have another priorities, coding scripts is not my real task but it makes everything easier)
- I had it running in my computer and it works perfectly, but running the same in the VM results in some unexpected problems.
- **The problem:** Most of time, it stops working in Copy-Item command. This is not an always, sometimes 4-5 files are copied and then something crashed and stop working.

**Code**

```
$folder = '\\SMT...\...\...\Desktop\testscript\Archiv' # Enter the root path you want to monitor.
$filter = '*.*'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here.
$backup = '\\...\...\...\Desktop\testscript\backup'  

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $true;
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {

    $name       = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp  = $Event.TimeGenerated
    $path       = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath

    Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green

    $path2      = Get-ChildItem $path
    $namedir    = $path2.Name
    $woname     = $path2 -replace [Regex]::Escape($namedir)
    $dest       = $woname -replace [Regex]::Escape($folder)
    $backupdest = "$backup\$dest"

    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $backupdest -Force -verbose
    Copy-Item -Path $path2 -Destination $backupdest -verbose -recurse

}
```

All the "path" stuff is to create the same folder tree as the origin.

I am doing something wrong? Is there maybe a easier way to do it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I researched a little bit, and I have the feeling that the problem is because I am running it from Powershell v3. When I do the same in Powershell v5 I do not have a problem. Could be that the reason why is not working?